# ASP.NET MVC 4 Reflection effect on performance

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, reflection

I am very new to ASP.NET MVC development, started 5 days ago. You can say just in R&D phase. I like the style of development of MVC but my confusion started when one of my friend told me that ASP.NET MVC's Performance is not comparable with WebForms because of  use of Reflection. e.g.:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FieldName)
```

MVC is using reflection. So according to him, we should use normal HTML Tags to overcome the reflection. e.g.

```
<input id="FieldName" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="" name="FieldName" data-val-required="FieldName is required." data-val="true" />
```

I tried to remove by confusion by searching over the internet and found following :

[ASP.NET MVC Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743/asp-net-mvc-performance) 
[Why use lambdas in ASP.NET MVC instead of reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768808/why-use-lambdas-in-asp-net-mvc-instead-of-reflection)
[Reflection and performance in web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657457/reflection-and-performance-in-web)

But these topics does not tell me clearly whether using normal HTML will give me more performance or not and what will be the best method in MVC large scale application.

Comment: Thats microoptimization. Are you ***sure*** that you need that performance gain? You probably gain a lot more speed by tuning your DB indexes.

Comment: @jgauffin That is what I thought at first. But I needed to remove my confusion by asking the experts as I am totally new. Thanks for taking some time. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reflection test does not show expected numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239310/reflection-test-does-not-show-expected-numbers)

Comment: Hmmmmm that improved my understanding of the reflection. So the summary is if you're not using it millions of time then there is no notable difference in performance. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are virtually guaranteed that the non-reflection version will be faster as it needs to do less work. However, I expected the difference to be quite small. I have done some basic tests with two different templates.

Template 1 using Html helpers:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FieldName)  
}
```

Template 2 using plain HTML:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    <input id="FieldName" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="" name="FieldName" data-val-required="FieldName is required." data-val="true" />
}
```

To test the performance, I have used the [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) library which gives us an idea on how much time is spent rendering the templates. When averaging the results, I get the following values:

- Template 1 (with HTML helpers): **405.8 ms**
- Template 2 (plain HTML): **82.1 ms**

The difference is thus **323.7 ms**, a factor 5 difference. However, we have done our test using 10000 iterations which probably isn't default behavior in a template. If we change the templates to a more sensible default like 10 times, we get the following results:

- Template 1 (with HTML helpers): **3.7 ms**
- Template 2 (plain HTML): **0.5 ms**

Now you can still see some difference (**3.2 ms**), but in my humble opinion this is negligible. At this point, I would not be looking at the performance at all but only look at what style you prefer. If you want to completely control your HTML, go for the plain HTML version. If you want to have all the extras the HTML helpers offer (like automatically translating annotations to jQuery validation attributes), go for that method. The difference between the two methods will in most cases be low enough to not have a large impact.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I will prefer to use both like in case where I just want to display data in a table then I think Simple HTML is good choice instead of HTML Helper to display label but in case of inserting and updating data, I think HTML helper will be a good candidate with it's build in features. :) Thanks for helping me out and telling me about this amazing tool MiniProfiler. I didn't know about that.

Comment: @UsmanKhalid A combination is valid too of course. Your use case sounds a valid case for using both. Enjoy the MiniProfiler, it is actually developed by the guys that built Stackoverflow.com.